# Named service in service.yml gives me autowire error

Tags: symfony

In symfony5 (it happened with me in symfony4 too, I just forgot the solution) I have strange behivor.

Here is the `service.yml` related part:

```
app.service.media.mediaresolve:
    class: Vaso123\Service\Media\MediaResolve
    arguments:
      [
        '%incomingPdf%',
        '%processedPdf%',
        '%workDir%',
      ]
```

If I am using like this, I am getting error:

> Cannot autowire service "Vaso123\Service\Media\MediaResolve": argument
> "$incomingPdf" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "array", you
> should configure its value explicitly.

Here comes the magic. If I remove the name and give exactly the class, it works:

```
Vaso123\Service\Media\MediaResolve:
    arguments:
      [
        '%incomingPdf%',
        '%processedPdf%',
        '%workDir%',
      ]
```

Why is it happens? The name does not matter, it could be `a.b`, `xxxxx`, anything.

Comment: That is a service alias, described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring). EDIT: I see you posted an answer and found it.

Comment: Your since deleted answer implies that this has something to do with aliases?  It's not.  It's about service ids.  In your first example you made a service with an id of app.service.media.mediaresolve.  Autowire comes along and encounters a class named MediaResolve.  Since there are no manually defined services with an id of MediaResolve, autowire tries to make it a service and fails.  The fact that you have another service using that class is irrelevant to autowire.  The best approach would have been to exclude MediaResolve from autowire.